# canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); not working in mozila firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

[This the output getting out "a blank image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORpbK.png)Can anyone provide a solution for this

```
downloadflowchart(node, workflowName) {
    const s = document.getElementById(node);
    if (s != null && s !== undefined) {
      const image = new Image();
      const xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(s);
      image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(xml);
      image.onload = function () {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = $($('#' + node)[0]).width();
        canvas.height = $($('#' + node)[0]).height();
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = workflowName + '.png';
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
      };
    }
  }
```

I had used like this but not working in firefox but working fine in the remaining browsers

HTML code is here:

```
   <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div *ngIf="graphDefinitionString!=''" style="float:right">
                                                                <div title="click to download flow chart."
                                                                    *ngIf="graphDefinitionString!=''"
                                                                    class="btn btn-default btn-circle"
                                                                    (click)="downloadflowchart('graphDiv',selectedWorkflowName);"
                                                                    style="padding:15px 0;">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-download fa-lg"
                                                                        aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div style="overflow:auto;">
                                                                 <div #mermaid></div>  
                                                               <!-- <app-flowchart
                                                                 [result]="graphDefinitionString"> 
                                                                </app-flowchart>-->
                                                                <div *ngIf="graphDefinitionString==''">Workflow not
                                                                    defined
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular or Typescript. And if have any HTML then please add it to your code example.

Comment: Also look at [How do I create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to create a snippet which we can examine for ourselfs. This will increase your chances of a good answer.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier can you please find the HTML attached

Comment: Thanks for adding it, still there is no way to tell what is happening for we can not run your code. Examine the link I provided you. It has instructions to create a "stack snippet" which we can run in our own browsers.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier can you guess what is happening in that canvas.toDataURL, there are some repeated letters are there in the image which i shared

Comment: No I can't guess it because I can't reproduce your issue.